# Using variables within a string - WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, string-interpolation

I am trying to use a common string as a variable to make my code more concise, but Selenium WebDriver keeps throwing the following exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

I thought it could be done with string interpolation as follows:

```
string common = "\"[data - test - code ^= 'ABC'] > ";

new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible((By.CssSelector($"{common}td.result__td.result__td--test > img"))));
```

...but no joy. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The string interpolation syntax is correct. Try to see if its result is relevant:
`"[data - test - code ^= 'ABC'] > td.result__td.result__td--test > img"`

Comment: That is exactly the result I am expecting, but I'm not sure how to check this and I don't understand why Selenium is complaining that the selector is invalid

Comment: Is it `data - test - code` or `data-test-code` that you are trying to match? Just `Console.WriteLine($"{common}td.result__td.result__td--test > img")` and see if it's what you are expecting it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium can't handle attributes like `data - test - code`. `data-test-code` for example (without spaces) would be acceptable. You need to find another way to locate that element.

By the way, you have a redundant `"` in the beginning of the selector.

Comment: My guess is that the spaces are the result of a bad copy/paste. If he tries, `string common = "[data-test-code ^= 'ABC'] > ";` I bet it will work.

Comment: It wasn't a copy/paste error; I really am looking for data - test - code - sounds like it's not possible though, so I guess I'll just have to not use a variable and just have repeated code :(